# undetected_chromedriver takes too long

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I'm using selenium and undetected_chromedriver for scraping memes from 9gag. I was testing the code by printing the title and it takes around 7 to 10 seconds. I'm not sure if it's normal. I wanted to know if there is a way to make this process faster.

This is my code:

```
 from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
 import undetected_chromedriver as uc

 options = Options()
 options.headless = True
 driver = uc.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
 driver.get("https://9gag.com/gag/a5EAv9O")
 print(driver.title)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some 9gag scraping when I was starting out:)

The reason your code is taking ages to run is perhaps because you're running `ChromeDriverManager().install()`? Which is installing it each time. You should only need to do it once.

Selenium takes a few seconds to start up, so it's not actually the

```
driver.get("https://9gag.com/gag/a5EAv9O")
print(driver.title)
```

That is taking long, but the spinning up. So don't worry and just keep going.

Comment: I just executed again taking your suggestion with the following code. `driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://9gag.com/gag/a5EAv9O")` It's still taking the same time around 10 seconds to get results.

Comment: Yes, the point is that it's the OPENING of the browser that's taking long. Once it's open, you should be able to do `driver.get` quite fast. Why don't you do a bunch more of those, and let me know how long that takes?